# bit slicing: finding minimum value

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, bitwise-operators

## Short version

I need to find the minimum value of 64 `uint8_t` variables encoded as bit slices.

i.e. each bit of the variables is encoded into eight separate `uint64_t`:

```
//Normal layout:
uint8_t values[64]; // This is what you normally use. 
                    // Finding minimum would be a simple 
                    // matter of a for loop

/***********************/

// BITSLICE layout:
uint64_t slices[8]; // This is what I have, due to performance 
                    // reasons in other parts of the code (not shown here)

slice[0]; //LSB: Least signignificant bit (for all 64 values)
slice[7]; //MSB: Most significant bit (for all 64 values)
```

**Now, how do I find out the minimum value of these?** (I do not care about it's position, only it's value)

## More context:

In reality I have a much longer array (than 64) of values inside an algorithm which already uses bit-slicing for performance reasons.

So what I have is actually more like (the question above was simplified):

```
uint64_t slices[8][100];
```

So what I really need is the minimum value out of all 100*64 values. But I figure this can be done in a regular for loop by applying the answer to the simplified question above.

EDIT: apparently my question wasn't as clear as I thought so It's been updated

Comment: I felt the question isn't understandable on first reading and isn't completely clear. Can you add a bit more detail of expected outcome?

Comment: Does it mean the minimum 8-bit value, or the minimum 64-bit value when they are put together? You also mention 64 `uint8_t` bit slice variables but only show 8 array elements.

Comment: Maybe you need a loop?

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are simple and efficient functions that compute the minimum and maximum values of the set of 64 byte values encoded as 8 `uint64_t` packs, each storing 1 bit of each of the 64 values:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t maxslice(const uint64_t s[8]) {
    uint8_t max = 0, bit = 0x80;
    uint64_t mask = ~0ULL;
    for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; bit >>= 1) {
        uint64_t x = s[i] & mask;
        if (x) {
            max |= bit;
            mask &= x;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

uint8_t minslice(const uint64_t s[8]) {
    uint8_t min = 0, bit = 0x80;
    uint64_t mask = ~0ULL;
    for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; bit >>= 1) {
        uint64_t x = ~s[i] & mask;
        if (x) {
            min |= bit;
            mask &= x;
        }
    }
    return ~min;
}
```

As can be verified on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/CUaW2Z), `clang` generates branchless code for both functions.

For your extended goal of computing the minimum of a larger set of values organized this way, `uint64_t slices[8][100]`, you could simply iterate this code on the array and compute the minimum incrementally. It might be worthwhile to test at each step of this loop if the absolute minimum of `0` has been found already. The tricky part is how the array is organized:

`uint64_t slices[8][100]` defines an array of 8 arrays of 100 `uint64_t`. In other words the layout in memory is 6400 low order bits, then 6400 bits of order 2, ..., finally 6400 bits of weight 128.

```
uint8_t minarray(const uint64_t s[8][100]) {
    uint8_t all_max = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        uint8_t max = 0, bit = 0x80;
        uint64_t mask = ~0ULL;
        for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; bit >>= 1) {
            uint64_t x = ~s[i][j] & mask;
            if (x) {
                max |= bit;
                mask &= x;
            }
        }
        if (all_max < max) {
            all_max = max;
            if (all_max == 255)
                break;
        }
    }
    return ~all_max;
}
```

In order to vectorize this code, we can transpose the loops: computing with `x` and `mask` as arrays of 100 `uint64_t` will produce the same result but will let the compiler vectorize some of the inner loops:

```c
uint8_t minarray1(const uint64_t s[8][100]) {
    uint8_t max = 0, bit = 0x80;
    uint64_t mask[100] = {
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
        ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL, ~0ULL,
    };
    for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; bit >>= 1) {
        uint64_t x[100];
        uint64_t xall = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            x[j] = ~s[i][j] & mask[j];
            xall |= x[j];
        }
        if (xall) {
            max |= bit;
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                mask[j] &= x[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return ~max;
}
```

Again clang generates [unrolled vectorized code](https://godbolt.org/z/BQPEAO). Benchmarking would tell if this approach gives better performance than the previous one.

Comment: I'm moving the accepted answer to this one as it is the most complete one regarding the additional context. And also because you show the max function as well, even though it wasn't asked for. +1

Answer (score 4):

I can think of at least two ways to do it.  The simplest is to just brute-force it: reconstitute each of the 64 integers, one at a time, via the appropriate bitwise arithmetic, and keep track of the minimum result.  Something along these lines:

```
uint8_t min = 0xff;

// iterate over the collection of values
for (uint64_t which = 1; which; which <<= 1) {
    // reconstitute one value in 'test'
    uint8_t test = 0;

    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) {
        // verify this decoding -- your bit order may be different:
        test += (!!(slices[bit] & which)) << bit;
    }

    // track the minimum
    if (test < min) {
        min = test;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it should also be possible to do it more quickly by scanning just once through `slices` and accumulating the minimum directly.  I haven't time to test this, but it should convey the general idea:

```
uint8_t min = 0xff;
uint64_t mask = ~(uint64_t)0;  // a mask of candidate positions; all bits initially set

for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {  // assumes slice 7 is most significant
    // which of the remaining candidates have this bit set:
    uint64_t bits_set = slice[i] & mask;

    // If at least one of the remaining candidates does not have this bit set
    if (bits_set != mask) {
        min ^= (1 << i);   // turn off this bit in the result
        mask ^= bits_set;  // remove the candidates that do have this bit set
    }
}
```

This latter is akin to a radix sort.

Comment: I like the second approach. Suppose you examine each 'row' of 64 bits from b7. If they are all `0` or all `1` then move to the next row. Otherwise eliminate all columns with a `1` bit, until only one column remains, or you complete b0 at which point there must be duplicate smallest values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
  {
  union
    {
    uint64_t slices[8];
    uint8_t  bits[64];
    } a_union;

  int     i;
  uint8_t min;

  for(i = 0 ; i < sizeof(a_union.slices)/sizeof(a_union.slices[0]) ; ++i)
    {
    a_union.slices[i] = (i+1) * 0x1122334455667788;
    printf("a_union.slices[%d] = 0x%"PRIX64"\n", i, a_union.slices[i]);
    }

  for(i = 0, min = 255 ; i < sizeof(a_union.bits) ; ++i)
    if(a_union.bits[i] < min)
      min = a_union.bits[i];

  printf("min = %u (0x%X)\n", min, min);
  }
```

[onlinegdb test here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyMMgVao8)

**EDIT**

Even better - use Duff's Device.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

uint8_t min_in_mem_block(uint8_t *p, size_t len)
  {
  /* Find the minimum byte value in the block of memory of length len pointed to by p */

  size_t  n   = (len + 7) / 8;
  uint8_t min = UINT8_MAX;

  switch (len % 8) 
    {
    case 0: do { min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 7:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 6:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 5:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 4:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 3:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 2:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
    case 1:      min = *p < min ? *p : min; p++;
               } while (--n > 0);
    }

  return min;
  }

int main()
  {
  uint64_t block[8];

  for(size_t i = 0 ; i < sizeof(block)/sizeof(block[0]) ; ++i)
    {
    block[i] = ((i+1) * 0x1122334455667788u) | 0x0101010101010101;
    printf("block[%zu] = 0x%"PRIX64"\n", i, block[i]);
    }

  uint8_t min = min_in_mem_block((uint8_t *)block, sizeof(block));

  printf("min = %" PRIX8 "\n", min);
  }
```

[onlinegdb test here](https://onlinegdb.com/ByAooPpjL)

Comment: Using union is not a good idea since that makes the code needlessly endianess-dependent. It is better to use bit shifts and masking on a uint64_t, so you get 100% portable code.

Comment: Also `(7+1) * 0x1122334455667788` will give you an integer overflow on a signed `long long` type. Use `u` suffix on the hex constant.

Comment: @Lundin: how does endianness matter for finding the minimum byte value in a 64-byte block of memory?

Comment: Endianess matters because portably you have no clue which byte that contained the minimum, even if you would print "byte 0" etc. It's generally not a good habit to use union for byte-wise type punning.

Comment: @Lundin: there's nothing in the requirements about knowing which byte contains the minimum - simply to find it.

Comment: +1 for a good idea (portability would be good, but it's not critical at this moment), unfortunately this doesn't work for me, see "More context" in the updated question.

Comment: Anyway, you need to fix the integer overflow bug.

Comment: I don't see how a union does "transpose the bit matrix".

Comment: @A.Nilsson - alternative implementation added.